# Integrating Stripe with WIX

Tags: php, stripe-payments

So I am stuck with this issue and couldn't find any solution on the internet. The problem is that recently I got a task to add stripe support on a website on WIX. If you don't know about WIX, it is a cloud-based web development platform that allows users to create HTML5 websites and mobile sites, through the use of their online drag and drop tools. Now I can insert HTML codes in the website but I can't process PHP files. So is there anyway I could access the php file on another source?

Like For Example

`<form action="testurl.com/process.php" method="POST"></form>`

OR if anyone knows how to integrate Strip with WIX, let me know please.

Thanks ..

Answer (score 1):

I've integrated stripe a few months back, and as I know, you need to have an server to process the charge - on client side, the stripe receives the visitor information and creates a token that you need to use on your server, and then you would use that token to create the charge. So basically on client side, the charge doesn't happen !

I belive 2checkout.com supports Stripe payments or another way is if you have your own company site and you could create an subdomain and there you can put your client logo, stripe form and process the charge and this subdomain to be used each time your client needs someone to pay him or a link from the wix site to this subdomain (SSL on your domain would be good to protect yourself from man-in-the-middle attacks, even if on client side -> stripe the connections are made with https conn).

Comment: As a note, you could try and process the form on a domain that has php (from your wix site) but I don't recommend that. Easiest for you would be to use an 3rd party site that processes stripe payments or the subdomain ideea that would be basically the same thing as an 3rd party site but fewer charges.